# Load YouTube live stream in my Android app from specific time

Tags: android, youtube-api

First time sorry for my English.

I'm using YouTube API to play YouTube live stream in my Android app. Is there any way to load video from a specific time (for example 5 minutes before live)?

`youTubePlayer.loadVideo(LiveStreamVideoID,6000000)` is not working. It loads video from current (live) position.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot control the playback of live stream videos unless the live stream is finished. You may check the [`player.seekTo(seconds:Number, allowSeekAhead:Boolean):Void`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#seekTo) method which seeks to a specified time in the video. Also these [queueing functions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Queueing_Functions) allow you to load and play a video, a playlist, or another list of videos. If you are using the object syntax described below to call these functions, then you can also queue or load a list of search results or a user's list of uploaded videos.

> The optional `startSeconds` parameter accepts a float/integer and specifies the time from which the video should start playing when [`playVideo()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#playVideo) is called. If you specify a `startSeconds` value and then call [`seekTo()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#seekTo), then the player plays from the time specified in the [`seekTo()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#seekTo) call. When the video is cued and ready to play, the player will broadcast a [`video cued` event](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#getPlayerState) (`5`).

Hope this helps!